external monitor out of range in linux
I recently installed ubuntu 22.04 desktop in my laptop and after installation when I connected my monitor it is saying out of range when I change the monitor's resolution to 1024x768 then the display is working when I change display resolution back to 1920x1024 again it is showing out of range. Is there any way to solve this issue

Yes do not set it to a range lower then it supports. 1024 by 768 is the range for very old small square monitors.
